# Extract hex code from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, extract

I am trying to pass a message using Node-Red (nodered.org) to a function.

So the message would be something like: `Can I have 00ff00 please?`

I am only interested in the hex code value and I need to parse the message and extract the hex with regex. This is the code I have:

```
var str = msg.payload;
var colorCode = str.match([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/g);
return colorCode;
```

Something is not right and I get an error saying `Unexpected token {`

It doesn't work even if I put `[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]/g` I get an `A is not defined` error, probably because it doesn't consider it a regex.

Comment: You are missing a "/" in front of your regex - it is `str.match(/some regex/g);`

Comment: also you can slightly shorten it with i modifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `/`

Use any of

`str.match(/[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/)` or

`str.match(/[a-f0-9]{6}/i)`

instead of `str.match([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})`

Now if your string may contain multiple HEX codes then use the following instead:

`str.match(/[a-f0-9]{6}/gi)` -> This will fetch an array of all such HEX codes and hence you can access each such instance using index to the array as follows:

```
str="Can I have 00fA00 and B0fA0c please?"
hex_codes=str.match(/[a-f0-9]{6}/gi);
//hex_codes[0]=="00fA00" and hex_codes[1]=="B0fA0c"
```

Here is the **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZY5d/)**

Comment: I still get undefined whatever I pass as an input
var str="Can I have 00ff00 please?"
var colorCode = str.match(/[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/);
return colorCode;

Output: undefined
It's the same even if I put the /g parameter and access the result with return colorCode[0];

Comment: No, not yet I still don't get any output

Comment: Cheers, it works.. only problem I have now is that I get Object [object Object] has no method 'match', but that's probably the framework I am using (NodeRed).. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a suggestion for you. Always check the `browser-console` to debug such issues.

Answer (score 2):

HEX color always starts from `#` and can has `3` or `6` digits value. Try `/^#[a-z0-9]{3}([a-z0-9]{3})?$/i`:

```
'#fff000'.match(/^#[a-z0-9]{3}([a-z0-9]{3})?$/i);//["#fff000", "000"]
'#fff'.match(/^#[a-z0-9]{3}([a-z0-9]{3})?$/i);//["#fff", undefined]
```

Also you have a misprint in(you forgot `regexp` start slash), fixed regexp:

```
/[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]/g
```

Shorter version for 6-digits only value:

```
'#fff000'.match(/^#[a-z0-9]{6}$/i);//["#fff000"]
```

Or multiple-color string check:

```
'#fff000 #aaabbb #ccc999'.match(/#[a-z0-9]{6}/gi);
```

Comment: For the sake of it let's say that all hex codes used are 6 digits.
So I now have this code:
'var colorCode = msg.payload.match(/[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/g);
return colorCode;'
It doesn't throw any more errors, but no matter what I put as an input, as long as the regex is correct I get "undefined"
I also tried using /i instead of /g, same effect
Thanks for your help

Comment: I edit my answer. I added 6-digits value only regexp.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed on the comments, you've missed an `/` in front of your Regex to satisfy Javascript's Regex syntax.

Also, I'd like to suggest you to put boundaries on your regex, just to avoid some weird scenarios (like catching "BABABABABA"). Also, as pointed on the comments below, #FFF is a valid value for the color, so your Regex could be further improved. The result is the following:

```
/\b([a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6})\b/i
```

**Catches:**

```
Can I have C0ffee please?
The color is #FFF
```

**Doesn't catch:**

```
Testing 00000ff0000 just to be safe!
Making sure BABABABABA doesn't get catched also :)
Checking #ffff
```

As a final note, you may want to consider using the pattern **#RRGGBB** to catch those HEX colors, simply because you may find valid english words with 6 characters with letters from A-F. So, if you want to do that, just add an `\#` in front of your regex:

```
/\#\b([a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6})\b/i
```

[Check this Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fR7wT0), it contains some examples of some inputs.

Comment: Fair enough, {3,6} then

Comment: @EvertonAgner ... that would still allow for #4444

Comment: 3 or 6 characters then? Sorry, didn't know it allowed other thing than 6 chars

Comment: yes. hex colors are 6 chars RRGGBB but if each color's value is the same double digit like 445566 then 456 is allowed, FF2288 > F28 etc..